# Maximum sum of sequence

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have sequence of x numbers and x-1 operators (+ or -), where the order of the numbers and the operators are fixed. For example 5-2-1+3. By different parentheses you get different values. For example (5 - 2)-1+3 = 5, 5-(2-1)+3=7 and so on. I am now interested in the maximum sum and best in linear run-time/memory space.

I think that this problem can be solved with dynamic programming, but I simply don't find a meaningful variant.

Comment: There's a simple dynamic programming solution where the subproblems are the largest and smallest sums you can make for each sub-range in the sequence.  It's not going to be linear time, though.

Comment: So the order of the operator is fixed?

Comment: May I know what is the main purpose behind the scene. Because you are making -2 as +2 in second example which is incorrect it should be -2-1 = -3 always. So what I mean it logically there is only one solution for this example which 5

Comment: @MattTimmermans Do you mean something like matrix chain multiplication algorithm?

Comment: @Glubus Yes, numbers and operators are fixed.

Comment: @AabirHussain what are you talking about? The second example is -(2 - 1) = - (1) = -1. Are you trolling?

Comment: Okay; you can't find a packaged solution for your problem.
Where are you stuck on writing your own?  You should be able to break this into smaller, recursive steps.  For the most part, DP (dynamic programming) merely speeds execution by avoiding reproducing work.

Comment: @Glubus don't you think It should be -(2+1) instead of   -(2 - 1).

Comment: @AabirHussain I see what you're saying now. You'd argue that - 2 - 1 should become (2 - 1) since we put the - in front of it, correct? The problem with this is that the first - in - 2 - 1 is bound to the 2 as much as the second one is bound to the 1. This means that the new body of the parentheses can either be (-2 + 1) or (2 - 1). In the first option, the new term should be coupled with a + operator since we multiplied it with -1, the second option (which is what this problem uses) remains coupled with a - operator.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is certainly a dynamic algorithm.
This would work in a recursive way, finding the maximum value that can be gotten for every range.

**Algorithm**: 
You could separate the numbers and the operators into different lists (if the first number is positive add `+` to the list first).

```
max_sum(expression, operators):
   if len(expression) == 1: return expression
   max_value = -float('inf')     # minus infinity
   length = len(expression)
   for i in range(length):
      left_exp = max_sum(expression[0:i], operators[0:i])
      right_exp = max_sum(expression[i:length], operators[i:length])
      value = operator[i].apply(left_exp, right_exp)
      if value  >= max_value:
         max_value = value
   return max_value
```

The main idea of the algorithm is that it checks the maximum sums in every possible range division, goes all the way down recursively and then returns the maximum sum it got.

The pseudo-code doesn't take into account a case where you could get a maximum value by substracting the minimum value of the right expression, but with a few tweaks I think you could fix it pretty fast.

I tried to make the pseudo-code as easy to convert to code as possible out of my head, I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Let an expression be a sequence of operator-number pairs: it starts with an operator followed by a number, and ends with an operator followed by a number. Your example `5-2-1+3` can be made into an expression by placing a `+` at the beginning: `+5-2-1+3`.

Let the head of an expression be its first operator-number pair, and its tail, the rest. The head of `+5-2-1+3` is `+5` and the tail, `-2-1+3`.

In this context, let parenthesizing an expression mean placing an opening parenthesis just after the first operator and a closing parenthesis at the end of the expression, like so: `+(5-2-1+3)`. Parenthesizing an expression with a positive head doesn't do anything. Parenthesizing an expression with a negative head is equivalent to changing every sign of its tail: `-(5 -2-1+3) = -5 +2+1-3`.

If you want to get an extremum by parenthesizing some of its subexpressions, then you can first make some simplifications. It's easy to see that any subexpression of the form `+x1+x2+...+xn` won't be split: all of its elements will be used together towards the extremum. Similarly, any subexpression of the form `-x1-x2-...-xn` won't be split, but may be parenthesized (`-(x1-x2-...-xn)`). Therefore, you can first simplify any subexpression of the first form into `+X`, where `X` is the sum of its elements, and any subexpression of the second form into `-x1-X`, where `X` is the sum of its tail elements.

The resulting expression cannot have 3 consecutive `-` operators or 2 consecutive `+` operators. Now, start from the end, find the first subexpression of the form `-a-b`, `-a+b-c`, or `-a+b`, and compute its potential minimum and its potential maximum:
`min(-a-b) = -a-b`
`max(-a-b) = -(a-b)`
`min(-a+b-c) = -(a+b)-c`
`max(-a+b-c) = -a+b-c if b>=c, max(-a+b-c) = -(a+b-c) if b<=c`
`min(-a+b) = -(a+b)`
`max(-a+b) = -a+b`

Repeat by treating that subexpression as a single operator-number pair in the next one, albeit with two possible values (its two extrema). This way, the extrema of each subsequent subexpression is computed until you get to the main expression, of which you can simply compute the maximum. Note that the main expression may have a positive first pair, which makes it a special case, but that's easy to take into account: just add it to the maximum.

Comment: Thank you very much, interesting consideration. But the runtime/storage space is then much worse O(n) or ? In the worst case the possibilities that have to be checked are doubled with every new subsequence.

Comment: Absolutely not. You only have two extrema per subexpression. That's linear both in time and space. You just need to compute these extrema using two possible values for the previous subexpression, which still yields a very limited number of things to check.

Comment: Sorry I was a little confused. Now I see of course also that you are absolutely right ! Concerning simplifications: from how many elements is this possible? So a subexpressions of the form +x1+x2+...+xn can also be simplified to X if n= 2 or? But with a subexpression of the form -x1-x2-...-xn at least 3 elements are needed or ?

Comment: `+x1+x2+...+xn` is simplified to `+X`, so for `n=2`, `+x1+x2` becomes `+(x1+x2)`, and for `n=1`, `+x1` becomes `+x1` (which is of course useless). Similarly, `-x1-x2-...-xn` is simplified to `-x1-X`, so for `n=3`, `-x1-x2-x3` becomes `-x1-(x2+x3)`, and for `n=2`, `-x1-x2` becomes `-x1-x2` (similarly useless). So yes, in the algorithm, you start at `n=2` and `n=3` respectively. Keep in mind that you don't *have* to do these simplifications, it's just easier to explain and implement the next steps.

Comment: Thank you. For example if we have 1-2-3-4 we get with the simplification: 1 -2-(3+4) = 1 -9 right ? And so this algorithm give -8 as an answer. But  1-(2-3-4) = 6 is the right answer.

Comment: Reread my answer, you pretty much skipped the most important section (the last two paragraphs). `+1-2-3-4` becomes `+1-2-7`. You then compute the extrema of `-2-7`, which are `-2-7 = -9` and `-(2-7) = +5`. Now you have the main expression `+1+X` with `X = -9` or `X = +5`. The maximum is achieved with `X=+5`, giving `+1+5 = 6`.